# Powerful image editor, similar to GIMP

Tags: android, image-editor

Does anybody know of a image editor for Android that meets the following requirements?

It *must*:

- Run without internet access
- Not be a repackaging of GIMP for Android, for one important reason: those have extremely difficult to use virtual mice
- Have brush, gradient, magic wand, select by color, and magnetic lasso tools or equivalent
- Undo history
- Be either free or extremely cheap

It would be nice if it also had:

- Support for layers
- Support for rendering SVGs
- Support for other common GIMP tools
- Support for other common GIMP filters

Comment: OK, welcome to SR then, Nonny. For a starter, take a look at my [Mini-Photoshops and Mini-Gimps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_edit#group_219) app listing while waiting for good recommendations here; you can also use [my search engine](https://android.izzysoft.de/catmin/applists/search) to check for photo editors coming without the `INTERNET` permission (not really many matches, sorry). If you find your wanted app there, feel encouraged to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and let us know. Good luck!

Comment: @Izzy Thanks so much!
You said that there would be very few photo editors without the Internet permission...
But all I need are photo editors that can _run_ without it, so the link you provided is actually very helpful, because many of those apps only need it for ads or similarly frivolous purposes.

Comment: Yupp, understood – just wanted to point out in case it's relevant (might be useful in other cases as well, where it could be important for privacy reasons :) Glad the list is helping you! Looking forward to your answer with your "best finding" :)